# Rewrite file with 0's. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, file, boost, filesystems

I want rewrite file with 0's. It only write a few bytes.

My code:

```
int fileSize = boost::filesystem::file_size(filePath);

int zeros[fileSize] = { 0 };

boost::filesystem::path rewriteFilePath{filePath};
boost::filesystem::ofstream rewriteFile{rewriteFilePath, std::ios::trunc};
rewriteFile << zeros;
```

Also... Is this enough to shred the file? What should I do next to make the file unrecoverable?

**EDIT:** Ok. I rewrited my code to this. Is this code ok to do this?

```
int fileSize = boost::filesystem::file_size(filePath);

boost::filesystem::path rewriteFilePath{filePath};
boost::filesystem::ofstream rewriteFile{rewriteFilePath, std::ios::trunc};

for(int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++) {
    rewriteFile << 0;
}
```

Comment: VLA's are a C thing (and perhaps a compiler extension)

Comment: Why not use a shredder tool?

Comment: Anyway, after a `trunc` there are no guarantees that the OS will write to the same disk sectors that the original file occupied.

Comment: Is overwriting 0's on an existing file enough?  Your choice, your requirements, so you tell us.  You might look at some commercial tools ... many years ago I used a product called ZTree, and its "Disk Washing function with DoD Sanitize option".

Comment: Also found:  "US Department of Defense in the clearing and sanitizing standard DoD 5220.22-M recommends the approach "Overwrite all addressable locations with a character, its complement, then a random character and verify" (see table with comments) for clearing and sanitizing information on a writable media. To conform this ..."

Comment: Rewrited my code. Is this ok now?

@BoPersson What should I use, if `trunc` isn't good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1. `int zeros[fileSize] = { 0 };`

   You are creating an array that is `sizeof(int) * fileSize` bytes in size. For what you are attempting, you need an array that is `fileSize` bytes in size instead. So  you need to use a 1-byte data type, like `(unsigned) char` or `uint8_t`.

   But, more importantly, since the value of `fileSize` is not known until runtime, this type of array is known as a "Variable Length Array" (VLA), which is a **non-standard** feature in C++. Use `std::vector` instead if you need a dynamically allocated array.
2. `boost::filesystem::ofstream rewriteFile{rewriteFilePath, std::ios::trunc};`

   The `trunc` flag truncates the size of an existing file to 0.  What that entails is to update the file's metadata to reset its tracked byte size, and to mark all of the file's used disk sectors as available for reuse. The actual file bytes stored in those sectors are not wiped out until overwritten as sectors get reused over time. But any bytes you subsequently write to the truncated file are not guaranteed to (and likely will not) overwrite the old bytes on disk.  So, do not truncate the file at all.
3. `rewriteFile << zeros;`

   `ofstream` does not have an `operator<<` that takes an `int[]`, or even an `int*`, as input. But it does have an `operator<<` that takes a `void*` as input (to output the value of the memory address being pointed at). An array decays into a pointer to the first element, and `void*` accepts *any* pointer.  This is why only a few bytes are being written.  You need to use `ofstream::write()` instead to write the array to file, and be sure to open the file with the `binary` flag.

Try this instead:

```
int fileSize = boost::filesystem::file_size(filePath);

std::vector<char> zeros(fileSize, 0);

boost::filesystem::path rewriteFilePath(filePath);
boost::filesystem::ofstream rewriteFile(rewriteFilePath, std::ios::binary);
rewriteFile.write(zeros.data()/*&zeros[0]*/, fileSize);
```

That being said, you don't need a dynamically allocated array at all, let alone one that is allocated to the full size of the file. That is just a waste of heap memory, especially for large files.  You can do this instead:

```
int fileSize = boost::filesystem::file_size(filePath);

const char zeros[1024] = {0}; // adjust size as desired...

boost::filesystem::path rewriteFilePath(filePath);
boost::filesystem::ofstream rewriteFile(rewriteFilePath, std::ios::binary);

int loops = fileSize / sizeof(zeros);
for(int i = 0; i < loops; ++i) {
    rewriteFile.write(zeros, sizeof(zeros));
}
rewriteFile.write(zeros, fileSize % sizeof(zeros));
```

Alternatively, if you open a memory-mapped view of the file (`MapViewOfFile()` on Windows, `mmap()` on Linux, etc)  then you can simply use `std::copy()` or `std::memset()` to zero out the bytes of the entire file directly on disk without using an array at all.

> Also... Is this enough to shred the file?

Not really, no. At the physical hardware layer, overwriting the file just one time with zeros can still leave behind remnant signals in the disk sectors, which *can* be recovered with sufficient tools. You should overwrite the file multiple times, with varying types of random data, not just zeros.  That will more thoroughly scramble the signals in the sectors.

Comment: Thank you. I got another idea. I want rewrite my file with random characters too (after rewriting with 0's). How can I do that?

Comment: @RichardZavodny You accept this answer and write the code to rewrite the file with random characters too

Comment: *You should overwrite the file multiple times, with varying types of random data, not just zeros. That will more thoroughly scramble the signals in the sectors.* And all of that might not matter if the data is stored in a copy-on-write filesystem such as ZFS or BTRFS...

Answer (score 2):

I cannot stress strongly enough the importance of the comments that overwriting a file's contents does not guarantee that any of the original data is overwritten. ALL OTHER ANSWERS TO THIS QUESTION ARE THEREFORE IRRELEVANT ON ANY RECENT OPERATING SYSTEM.

Modern filing systems are extents based, meaning that files are stored as a linked list of allocated chunks. Updating a chunk may be faster for the filing system to write a whole new chunk and simply adjust the linked list, so that's what they do. Indeed copy-on-write filing systems *always* write a copy of any modified chunk and update their B-tree of currently valid extents.

Furthermore, even if your filing system doesn't do this, your hard drive may use the exact same technique also for performance, and any SSD almost certainly always uses this technique due to how flash memory works. So overwriting data to "erase" it is meaningless on modern systems. Can't be done. The only safe way to keep old data hidden is full disk encryption. Anything else you are deceiving yourself and your users.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, overwriting with random data:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c1b473cc2713e5d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <random>
namespace bio = boost::iostreams;

int main() {
    bio::mapped_file dst("main.cpp");

    std::mt19937 rng { std::random_device{} () };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<char> dist;

    std::generate_n(dst.data(), dst.size(), [&] { return dist(rng); });
}
```

Note that it scrambles its own source file after compilation :)